# How to update the list in react native expo get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

The code, when working with which, when loading the page, a list of tasks from the database should appear and when adding tasks, the list should change

```
    const [jsonValue, setjsonValue] = useState([]);
    const [message, setmessage] = useState([]);
    const [messageInput, setmessageInput] = useState('');
    const [object, setObject] = useState([]);

    const jsonToken = async () =>{
        console.log('1');
        setjsonValue( await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_token'));
    };
    
    
    
    const token = {
        params:{
            token: typeof jsonValue === 'string' ? jsonValue.replace(/['"]+/g, '') : '',
        }
        
    }

    const Postmessage = () => {
        
        axios.post(`${baseUrl}`, configData)  
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Сервер ', error);
        })
    }

    const MessageLoad = () =>{
        axios.get(`${baseUrl}`, token)
            
        .then(res => {
            setmessage(res.data.response.tasks)
            setObject(Object.values(message));
                    
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        jsonToken();   
        MessageLoad();
    }, []);
```

I've been sitting for days, I can't update the list when loading the page and adding new words to the list

Answer (score 0):

you may just call the MessageLoad function on the Postmessage function

```
const Postmessage = () => {
        
        axios.post(`${baseUrl}`, configData)  
        .then(res => {
            MessageLoad()
            console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Сервер ', error);
        })
    }
```

Comment: I need it to be constantly updated, since when loading this page, existing messages should be loaded

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).